# Activity Alarm do not turn on screen in Sony Xperia P when alarm played

Tags: java, android, keyguard, keyguardlock

My alarm program on Android does not work on many Samsung and HTC devices; it does not turn on the screen and does not play alarm until the screen is manually turned on.
This problem is in Sony Xperia P and Huawei Honor phone...
I use any thing that I think solve my problem in my code, but it isn't fixed! :(

This is my code:

```
try {

    // baraye roshan kardane safe va roshan negah dashtane oon dar Huawei honor
    PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) PlayAlarmActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK 
         | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Power Manager");                   
    mWakeLock.acquire();                    
    Log.i("Unlock Screen", "1");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error in playalarmactivity for unlock screen 1 ...", e.toString());
}           

try {
    // Set the window to keep screen on
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    Log.i("Unlock Screen", "2");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error in playalarmactivity for unlock screen 2 ...", e.toString());
}

try {
    // baraye baz kardane lock dar gooshihayi mesle sonye Masoud!!! :D
    km = (KeyguardManager) PlayAlarmActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
    kl.disableKeyguard();                     
    Log.i("Unlock Screen", "3");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error in playalarmactivity for unlock screen 3 ...", e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Comment: thanks, i used this permission. please read my question one more time. my app work correctly but not in all Android devices... :(